# Let f(x) = x. Find the multiplicative inverse of f(x) + I in Q[x]=I.

Tags: field-theory

I know that the inverse function of $y=x$ is $x=y$, which is the same function. I also understand that the multiplicative inverse of a function is its reciprocal, ie. the multiplicative inverse of $f(x)=x$ is $\frac1x$.

Applying that to $f(x) + I$, where $I$ is an irrational number ie, $\sqrt 2$, then the multiplicative inverse would be $\frac1{x + \sqrt 2}$

How do I prove this in General terms?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why the tag "field theory"? And why does this seem more like a problem such as: "find the inverse of $f(x)+I$ in the *quotient ring* $\mathbb Q[x]/I$, where $f(x)$ is the *polynomial* $x \in \mathbb Q[x]$, and $I$ is some *ideal* of $\mathbb Q[x]$"?

Comment: So, should "$Q[x]=I$" be $Q[x]/I$? Wlado, we think you have misinterpreted the question and copied it incorrectly.

Comment: Care to engage with the comments, Waldo?

Comment: I guess Waldo has lost interest.